# Spring Boot with Security - tests fail to load context

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a Spring boot app and just added security to it. That breaks my tests as the context won't even load.

Tests are dealing with service and persistence layers, so the security should not affect them at all. That is meant for the controllers.

I followed an official github sample and have this simple security configuration:

```
@Configuration
@Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)
public class ApplicationSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.antMatcher("/**").csrf().disable();

        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/user").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
    }
}
```

Running the app works fine and as expected. But running tests, such as:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = DeadlinesApplication.class)
public class TaskDAOHibernateTest {
    @Test
    @Transactional
    public void someTest() {...}
}
```

Fails with:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'applicationSecurity': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.setAuthenticationConfiguration(org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
```

Adding the `@EnableWebSecurity` annotation to the class does allow the tests to pass, however in the docs there is written:

```
To switch off the default web security configuration completely you can add a bean with @EnableWebSecurity
```

And I want to keep the default configuration, only selectively override it.

Comment: Try adding `@WebAppContext` to your test.

Comment: What package is it supposed to be from? I cannot find it anywhere.

Comment: My bad.. I meant, `@WebAppConfiguration`.